# Deselect cell after swipe on not deletable row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `TableView` with three sections. Section one and two can be deleted, (delete with swipe)
section three can't. My problem now is that when I swipe on a cell in the third section, it gets selected. I tried deselecting it when "`canEditRowAtIndexPath`" is called(and it really gets called), but that doesn't work and the cell remains selected. My "`canEditRowAtIndexPath`" looks like this:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great workaround.
A swipe on the cell, forces the app to call `viewWillAppear`.
Add `[self.tableView reloadData];`into that method and the selected state will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I found ( in my opnion ) a better solution to this matter

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:   UITableViewRowAnimation.Right)
```

I hope that helps!! 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You may check and close the 3rd section cell selections in `-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` by using `tableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];` in this method -

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Or in -

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
Set selection style none. `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called when I swipe on the cell... if you just swipe, you don't select, but the cell gets highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method of `UITableView`

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```